# EclipseLink JPA 2.0. "unknown enum constant javax.persistence.LockModeType.NONE"

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a Glassfish v3 with a remote EJB. I use this EJB to manipulate a data base using EclipseLink. Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267692/error-on-client-side-while-calling-a-business-method-on-server-side-returning-ma) question, i'm now trying to import the EclipseLink jars to my client application as @James suggested.

Here are the jars i have added so far, those jars are those added on the server side of my application.

- eclipselink-2.3.2.jar
- javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.1.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar

But when i try to compile my netbeans module, i got this error:

```
error: in class file javax/persistence/NamedQuery.class(javax/persistence:NamedQuery.class): unknown enum constant javax.persistence.LockModeType.NONE
Note: Attempting to workaround javac bug #6512707
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: [javax.ejb.Remote]
error: in class file javax/persistence/NamedQuery.class(javax/persistence:NamedQuery.class): unknown enum constant javax.persistence.LockModeType.NONE
1 error
```

Why?

Comment: Execute `System.out.println(NamedQuery.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());` somewhere in your code and see what that points you to. Then get rid of that JAR, it's JPA 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems like you have the JPA 1.0 jar first on your classpath, but need the JPA 2.0 classes.

Comment: See [this](http://bb10.com/java-jasig-cas-user/2011-05/msg00104.html) for possible solution